# Double limit and iterated limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was hanging on the following statement.

"If the double limit $\displaystyle \lim_{(x_1, x_2) \rightarrow (a_1, a_2)} f(x_1, x_2)$ and the iterated limit $\lim_{x_1 \rightarrow a_1} \lim_{x_2 \rightarrow a_2} f(x_1, x_2)$ exist, then they will be equal."

Towards this statement I was thinking the function $x \sin \tfrac{1}{y} + y \sin \tfrac{1}{x}$. But for this function, the iterated limit does not exist.

Can you give a counterexample of the statement.

Comment: @Kavi: I hope no. Take $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (x \sin \tfrac{1}{y} + y \sin \tfrac{1}{x})$ and $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} (x \sin \tfrac{1}{y} + y \sin \tfrac{1}{x})$. Do you have any authentic source for your statement?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy you are wrong.  Taking $f(x,y)=x\sin \frac{1}{y}+y\sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $xy \ne 0$ and $f=0$ for $xy = 0$ gives counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is in John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), page 184, the existence of double limit and either of the two iterated limits, finite or infinite, implies the equality of double and that iterated.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof. Zkutch

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask more when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\lim_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = L$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $x$ satisfies $0< \|x-\alpha\| < \delta$ then
$|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $x_1$ satisfies $0 < |x_1 - \alpha_1 | < {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \delta$, then for $0 < |x_2 - \alpha_2 | < {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \delta$ we have
$0< \|x-\alpha\| < \delta$ (with $x=(x_1,x_2)$) and so $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

In particular, the two limits are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof. Zkutch

Comment: I usually go by a different name :-).